# How do I access an EF db context in a BackgroundService class in a Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, background-service, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a Web API end point which inserts items in a queue (class `ReportQueue`).

I have a class which does some database processing per queue item (class `ReportCollection`).

I have a `BackgroundService` subclass which dequeues an item from the queue and passes it on to the class (class `WorkerService`).

I'm able to register these classes in `Startup.ConfigureServices` as below:

```
services.AddHostedService<WorkerService>().AddSingleton<IReportQueue<QueueItem>, ReportQueue<QueueItem>>();
services.AddScoped<IReportCollection, ReportCollection>();
```

But I'm in a dilemma over the db context - how do I pass it to the `ReportCollection` class?

- `ReportCollection`, being a POCO, is not eligible for DI.
- I cannot inject it into `WorkerService`, because I get an exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'DbContext'
from singleton Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.
```

- trying to get a reference to the db context from within `WorkerService` does not work - the entire code block just gets skipped for some reason when the `var dbc...` line is uncommented:

```
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{

    var rc = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IReportCollection>();
    //var dbc = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
    rc.GetReport();

}
```

Anything else I can try?  Am using .Net Core 3.1, btw.

Comment: Whats POCO? Explain pls

Comment: What does the block is skipped mean  in case you request the db context on the scope ? If you use .GetRequiredService and its not possible to resol.ve the service this throws an exception ? Is there any exception getting caught maybe and if yes what does the exception looks like?

Comment: @HirasawaYui plain old CSharp object.

Comment: @Retrogott there is no exception thrown - but I had some log statements within the block which did not get printed.

Comment: Did you try to catch an Exception with a custom try catch block ? Seems that not always the exceptions are logged in that case. See [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2363)

Comment: @Retrogott Thank you for the link - it was very helpful.  Very strange bug!
After moving the `await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);` line to the end of the try/catch block, am able to catch the exceptions. There are some related to circular dependencies in the DbContext models.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just create that collection class inside that WorkerService?

Like, `var collection = ReportCollection>()`.

You can place it into your constructor and create instances instead of using DI.

Comment: Hi, well, the collection class is used in other places, so I can't just move it into the WorkerService.  Also, I still need to pass the DbContext to the constructor of the collection class. That is the bigger problem.